# Triggering Build on Package Update

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, artifactory

I'm looking for options that would allow us to trigger/queue builds (XAML Build Definitions within Azure DevOps) when a new package is available in either Azure DevOps Artifacts or Artifactory.

We've developed a common framework library, which we build, package and post to a NuGet Repository (either Artifactory or Azure DevOps Artifacts).  Naturally, each time we post, we increment the version number: x.y.z.n, x.y.z.n+1, x.y.z.n+2...

We also have other components which reference this common framework using NuGet Floating versions:  x.y.z.*  Some of these components have interfaces that other components also reference and so on.

We want to trigger the rebuilds of components when a new version of a referenced package is posted to the repository.

For example:  If a change to our Common Framework is made and a new version (x.y.z.15 for example) is posted to the NuGet Repository, we want to trigger/queue all the other builds which reference the Common Framework Package Version x.y.z.*.

We've been looking for existing tools to do this but so far no luck.  Here are some ideas/strategies we have:

1) Does something exist or could something be built to subscribe to a Library in a Repository, that build could be triggered when a new version appears

2) Should we build a list of all the package references and builds which need to be triggered somewhere and write a program to do this.

3) Can we chain builds within Azure DevOps or can they subscribe to successful builds - forget about the Repository - just trigger from successful builds of the components you depend on... everything is in the same Azure DevOps code repository.

While we're using Azure DevOps, we're not using the GIT repository, we're using the older VS Repo and we've got the older XAML builds, not the Pipelines yet.

Comment: What version of TFS are you using? You could probably create some frankenstein process using service hooks and REST APIs, but it would be ugly.

Comment: Everything is now in Azure DevOps but our XAML build definitions date back to TFS 2013 and have not been upgraded to Pipelines.  Regarding the Frankenstein,it's what I'm hoping to avoid, but it's a real possibility.

Comment: Since your question is broad, I cannot answer all your questions, and simply answer your first two questions, first question, the answer is no, we could 
enable continuous integration, but we could use it to monitor the Library version in a Repository, second, the answer is no, we could not list the package references and builds, because the continuous integration only support Branch and path.